# How do I send data to an 8-channel USB Relay device from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, relay

Part of a project I'm working on requires sending bytes to an 8-channel relay board. I've identified the board as `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I've found some tutorials on the internet, but they're either out of date, for Windows, or looking at a different device than I'm looking at. The device I'm looking at is one like this:

[image]

Is there something I've missed? How do I send data to this?

Comment: Solutions would be greatly accelerated if you edit your question to include a part number or, better yet, a link to a data sheet.

Comment: At least provide the output of `lsusb` though even that might not be giving the necessary details to identify the board, e.g. if it is using some kind of a generic USB-to-whatever bridge. Since you bought it one would guess you know make and model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093Y89DE) is the product you have, have a look this [customer comment](https://www.amazon.com/review/R1468S8GHPHZ2D/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0093Y89DE) who has graciously left some breadcrumbs on how to control the device. As some other customers have noted, the product cycles (ON/OFF) the relays on power up and also malfunctions in certain cases you might want to take the right precautions when using it in your application.

There is download link below the comments to a rar file that contains some documentation and device drivers for windows

Here is an extract from the documentation

> Characteristics:
>
> 8 SPDT relays SRD-12VDC-SL-C
>
> Relay specification – 10A 250VAC/10A 125VAC/10A 30VDC /10A 28VDC
>
> Power Supply - 12 VDC
>
> Current consumption - 300 mA
>
> FT245RL. Datasheet –( http://www.ftdichip.com/)
>
> Led for each relay output
>
> Power Led
>
> USb led
>
> Size - 93mm / 70mm / 16mm
>
> Supported by DRM Software
>
> Windows software examples: VB6, BCB6, Java (netbeans), VB.NET 2010 Express, 
>   C++.NET 2010 Express
>
> PCB parameters: FR4 / 1.5mm / two layers / metalized holes / HAL / white stamp / solder mask
>
> Extra PCB openings for better voltage isolation
>
> Doubled high current tracks
>
> Important:
>
> When the board is connected to the PC and the PC is restarted, the relays will 
>   be toggled several times. This is because of the structure of the FTDI chip.
>
> The device must be supplied with 12 VDC or order to work.
>
> There is no protection against reversed voltage! If the VCC(+12V) and GND are 
>   reversed the board will be damaged!
>
> The board can not work without computer

Briefly (incase the link(s) go dead sometime) the relay board appears to use a FTDI chip (USB => USART) and therefore should be simple to control by writing to the serial port like so (taken from a customer's comment on amazon and modified to include more examples)

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial(port='COM15', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=None)
s.isOpen()
s.write([b'\00',b'\00'])  # all off
s.write([b'\xFF',b'\xFF']) # all on
```

the protocol appears to be `<mask> <value>` where

`<mask>` is a 8 bit number, with relays corresponding to bits set 1 get affected by the value

`<value>` is a 8 bit number, 0 turns off, 1 turns on

so talking in hex, `0f`, `0a` should affect the first 4 relays (`0f`), turning relays 4 and 2 on and 3 and 1 turned off.