# Pi 4 w - FPP6.2 - how to communicate from FPP on Pi 4 w to a USB 8 channel relay

Tags: pi-4, usb, relay

Similar question as the one posted in 2016 ([How do I send data to an 8-channel USB Relay device from a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55541/how-do-i-send-data-to-an-8-channel-usb-relay-device-from-a-raspberry-pi))

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 w connected to a SainSmart USB 8 channel relay, running FPP 6.2, using Vixen to create a Christmas light display. Using the USB relays to turn on 120v Christmas strings of lights.

Using FPP 6.2 (https://falconchristmas.com/forum/index.php?topic=15716.0 ) but doesn't communicate to the USB relay board.  The relay board cycles through when connected to the Pi.

Here is the model of USB relay that I'm using:
[https://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Eight-Channel-Relay-Automation/dp/B0093Y89DE/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0093Y89DE)

This is my first experience using a Pi and FPP and I'm not a programmer so have no idea what I'm doing.  I've searched all over the web but can't find anything current about using a USB relay board in this manner.

[image: USB relay appears to show up in FPP]

Comment: This poorly documented product has no detail and appears to be dependent on a custom OS. Caveat emptor!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send data to an 8-channel USB Relay device from a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55541/how-do-i-send-data-to-an-8-channel-usb-relay-device-from-a-raspberry-pi)